# Do we need a random number generator to decipher (decrypt)?

Tags: random, encryption

I'm by far an expert on encryption and therefor am seeking out software deciphering advice.  My example bellow deals with hardware, but my question is to seek software advice on whether a software solution is feasible, doable and reasonable.

Background:

On our product, we are considering adding encryption on our RFID keys.  Our current firmware does not support this and our hardware guy now wants to upgrade the hardware to add a random number generator chip.

As mentioned above, I'm no expert on encryption, but I always though that a random number generator was required for the ciphering, but not for the decipher?

Additional info: We are using a low power ARM processor (don't know the model at this time).

So my questions are as follows:

1. Do you really need random numbers to decipher data?
2. If so, why wouldn't a standard C language library be sufficient?

And lastly,

1. If we do need random numbers to decipher, can anyone with experience comment of the benefits/disadvantages of having hardware vs. software random numbers?  Example: Is the random number portion of a decipher only 1% of the total processing and thus I would not     necessarily speed things up?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion is because in this case the random numbers are not being used for randomness. Many cryptographic algorithms such as RC4 are based on XORing the plaintext with a cryptographically secure pseudorandom random number generator (CSPRNG) initialized with the key as a seed. (pseudorandom means the random number generator uses a algorithm to generate values) The data is then decrypted by again using the CSPRNG with the key and XORing it against the ciphertext.

> 1. If so, why wouldn't a standard C language library be sufficient?

No, as almost all rand() implementations use an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which is insecure and not suited for cryptographic purposes.

> If we do need random numbers to decipher, can anyone with experience
>   comment of the benefits/disadvantages of having hardware vs. software
>   random numbers? Example: Is the random number portion of a decipher
>   only 1% of the total processing and thus I would not necessarily speed
>   things up?

As is explained, generating values using the CSPRNG takes up virtually all the computing power required for encryption; the only other step is XORing the CSPRNG with the plaintext/ciphertext. However, I don't think you need a hardware accelerated pseudorandom generator as RC4 only requires 7 cycles a byte on a Pentium and most practical cryptographic algorithms less than 100 cycles per byte. If it needs to encrypt faster than hundreds of megabytes a second, then a hardware accelerated pseudorandom generator would accelerate the encryption significantly.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!  Are you saying that the seed is saved somewhere with the ciphered result?  Additionally, given a seed, the same 'set' of random numbers can be created, correct?

Comment: @Jeach The seed is the key, the secret "password" one uses to encrypt the data.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.  I keep thinking of an encrypted file system (FS) and wonder why deciphering data from that would work without special hardware, but in the case described in my question, special hardware would be required.  Would a FS data be less secure than data off of a RFID key?

Comment: @Jeach Special hardware is not necessary as it only needs a pseudorandom source (a random number generator based on an algorithm). [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), a famous but not so secure stream cipher only takes 7 cycles per byte on a Pentium.